# Meteor : Access to my public/lib from server

Tags: meteor

According to the Meteor Doc, the public fodler is accessible for both server and client. But, if I just need to use the HTML head elements to access it, how can I do it from server ?

I made a lib with very specific functions, and I'm tired of copy pasting them at the top of each of my server .js file.

Could anyone give me the tip ? I couldn't find out on google :/

Thanks you,

David

Comment: Is there a reason you are not using the `lib/shared` folder rather than `public`? `public` is usually reserved for various assets while `lib/shared` can have libraries shared between the client and server.

Comment: Oh okay, i didnt know that.

Still, have I to declare some lines of code server side in order to access it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are making your life harder than necessary. *Any* folder that is not called `client`, `server`, `private`, or `public` is shared by the client and the server. Just put your shared `.js` files into any folder, say, `/common`, and they will be available (loaded) on both the client and the server.

The `public` folder is specifically for assets that are *not* loaded automatically by the server, but are instead served statically over HTTP, similar to the static functionality of express. It's the place for images and other assets you want on the client.

Comment: I did like you said : I put my lib in a /common folder. But now, no matter that I call my functions from client or server, I always get an exit with code 8 as meteor is unable anymore to find my function. :/

Comment: is the function defined as `functionname = functio(args) {..}` or as `function functionname(arg) {..}`. You need to use the former. If you do, it will be loaded and available everywhere. With the latter it is only visible in the file itself.

Comment: I do well use it like this : function getLangLevelColor(lvl) { ... }
Put it on /common/lib.js, then on /lib.js, none is working, I get the same error :/

Comment: well then that is your problem. As I was saying, that doesn't work. You need to use the functionname = function() .. notation.

Comment: My bad, I'm not a english native speaker, thought that former meant previous ^^