# How to read json file located in both folder in meteor?

Tags: javascript, meteor

I need to read a language json file from both folder but in client side seems not accessible.

Comment: Where did you put the file? did you try to put it inside the public folder on the root of your app?

Comment: I need to put it just in both folder not in public folder, because I need to write on it

Comment: Then please specify that in the body and title of your question. I think Zim's answer could be of help to you.

Answer (score 1):

you should familiarize yourself with the Meteor application structure, which you can find here:

https://guide.meteor.com/structure.html

there are a couple different ways to do what you want. following the guide, i have such code in the /imports area, in a directory that is served to both client and server. e.g.

/imports/api/foo/foo.json:

```
{
  "foo": "bar",
  "baz": "bat"
}
```

/imports/api/foo/Foo.js:

```
let fooJson = require('./foo.json');

const FooData = {
    foo: fooJson.foo,
    baz: fooJson.baz
};

export {FooData};
```

now, on either client or server, you can import FooData:

```
import {FooData} from '/imports/api/foo/Foo';
```

... and FooData is available to your JS code.

Answer (score 0):

In Meteor, any resouce file (jpeg, gif, txt, json, etc.) that you wish to make available to the client side must be placed in top level folder called **[public](https://guide.meteor.com/structure.html#special-directories)**.

From the client, you can access this data as if it was in the top level (eg. don't include `/public`). For example, if you had file `data.json` in `/public`, you can access it from the browser at `/data.json`.

Accessing this folder from the server is a bit trickier.  I haven't tried this in the latest 1.4 release, but you used to be able to access the public folder like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32099887/meteor-access-to-my-public-lib-from-server).

```
path.join(__meteor_bootstrap__.serverDir, "../web.browser/app");
```

With that said, you might want to step back a think about why you need the data. If you don't actually need the data in a literal file, then i would put the json on the server only  to simplify accessing it there and then serve it to the client via a meteor [method](http://docs.meteor.com/api/methods.html).

Comment: It works for me like this :   var frfileName = process.env.PWD +'/both/I18N/fr/fr.i18n.json';